# Load remote image into background-url (css) via jquery with error handling

Tags: jquery, ajax, background-image

On the page, I have a  with a certain image as the background-url css property.

What I want to have happen is to load a 2nd (remote) image via jquery/ajax (into the background-url property), and if there is an error of any kind retrieving the image, to load a secondary "default" image.

How would I accomplish such a thing?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          // Handler for .ready() called.
            $.ajax({
                    url: "/loadimageurl.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: data,
                    // callback handler that will be called on success
                    success: function(imageUrl, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        // log a message to the console
                        console.log("Hooray, it worked! Load The Image Here");
                        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
                    },
                    // callback handler that will be called on error
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        DefaultimageUrl = 'path/to/default/image.jpg';                        
                        // log the error to the console
                        console.log(
                            "Load Default Image here! The following error occured: "+
                            textStatus, errorThrown
                        );
                        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + DefaultimageUrl + ')');
                    }
                });


        });
```

When the page loads ajax called will be fired and `loadimageurl.php` will be called. Data variable post the data to the php script if you need to. If the call is successful(return the image url from the php script) you set the image url else error function will set the default image url.

Read the comments to understand the steps correctly and use console to check how the ajax calls are being executed and return the data. If you have any issues let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to come up with:

```
$(function() {
    var main_image = '';
    var second_image = '';
    $.ajax({url: main_image, cache: false, success: function(d) {
        console.log('success');
        $('#bg').css('background',main_image);                
    }, error: function() {
        console.log('failure');
        $('#bg').css('background',second_image);
    }});    
});​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sVZdK/

I was unable to test it with images, but I believe it will work.